# Display Long String in a Screen

Tags: html, database, flutter

My goal is to display large amounts of data, such as a book's text and table, inside a screen where the searched word is displayed.

The content of the documents is formatted as HTML and converted from Word. However, due to the abundance of data, loading (displaying) takes a long time, and the texts are also incomplete.

How can I make the process less and more efficient?

What other methods would you suggest?

Comment: Do you have a custom backend for your app? By custom, I mean written in nodejs or something else. If you are directly using firebase, then there is no other solution than splitting your data in chunks and fetching them in app one by one.

Comment: I am using SQLite and converting the database to JSON

Comment: Share current implementation.